# Override Function Return Types in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, interface, casting

I want to override a function's return type in order to alias it. It's easy enough to accomplish this but I can't find a solution without redefining the function's parameters, violating the DRY principle.

The practical application is to have a common function that returns data from a REST API.

```js
// this function resolves with some object (e.g. from a REST call)
function doStuff<T>(data: string): Promise<T> {
    return Promise.resolve(<any>{
        data,
        isStuff: true
    });
}

// I know `doStuff()` will resolve with an object matching this interface
interface CoolStuff {
    data: string;
    isStuff: boolean;
    isCool: boolean;
}

// I want to alias `doStuff()` to return `CoolStuff`-typed data but without restating the signature
// the `data` parameter is already present in `doStuff()`
const doCoolStuff: <T = CoolStuff>(data: string) => Promise<T> = doStuff;

doCoolStuff('data') // correct return and parameter types but not DRY
```

Comment: Why don't you call `doStuff` with the interface defined, as: `doStuff< CoolStuff >`?

Comment: This is for a client library and want to provide the type for my end-users.

Comment: I'm not sure that I've understand the question but how about simply calling ``doStuff<CoolStuff >('data')`` and without overriding? It will return a Promise<T> that will be a Promise<CoolStuff>

Comment: Similar to what Behrooz asked, I need to provide an interface where the user doesn't have to know what data type to use. I want them to be able to call `doCoolStuff()` and not have to know what type it should be returning, etc. It's just a cleaner API.

Comment: I thought this interface is being provided to you by another library. In this case, why don’t you just change the return type of `doStuff` to `Promise<CoolStuff>` and get rid of `<T>` for the function generic type?

Comment: I need `doStuff()` to be "generic" and support multiple response types. E.g. `Promise<CoolStuff>`, `Promise<HotStuff>`, `Promise<OtherStuff>`